# PHP sessions seems to be in conflict with CSS rules

Tags: php, css, session

I'm really confused! I've this php file in which i placed this script for redirect the user to the main page in case he haven't logged-in

```
<?php 

session_start();
if(!isLogged())
{
     header("location: mainarea.php");
     exit;  
}

function isLogged()
{return $_SESSION;}

?>
```

The page always worked but yesterday i've added this css rule in the same php file:

```
#deleteThumb
{
    position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px; width:20px; height:40px; left:320px;
}
```

And the redirection won't work anymore!!!! All what is placed before the php session control is rendered, after it, nothing Why? It's seems a bug of the php, i've not other explainations

**UPDATE:** Placing the session at the first line og the script, all return to work!

Anyway this is a real mistery!!
for exemple, this always worked:

```
<style>
    #wrapper{width:1000px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; padding-top:70px;}
</style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <?php session_start();
    if(!isLogged())
    {
         header("location: mainarea.php");
         exit;  
    }

    function isLogged()
    {return $_SESSION;} ?>
```

This istead don't work

```
<style>
    #wrapper{width:1000px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; padding-top:70px;}
    #deleteThumb{position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px; width:20px; height:40px; left:320px;}
  </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <?php session_start();
    if(!isLogged())
    {
         header("location: areanegozianti.php");
         exit;  
    }

    function isLogged()
    {return $_SESSION;} ?>
```

Comment: I want to clarify that removing the css rule all return to works fine

Comment: that's because you have to session_start() before ANYthing.

Comment: Where did you add that?

Comment: Can you show the file "after" you add CSS rules?

Comment: You can't output any text before calling `header()` or `session_start()`.

Comment: As the docs(http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) state, **"To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser."**.

Comment: I know that must be used before any output, but i always placed the css rules before it and alway worked... Strangly adding those other rule all stop to works.. Really strange!
Anyway i initialized first the css and after the session check, at the beginning of the body before any output

Comment: @AnnaLica Read my answer below! it shows the correct way of using a header. Styles use html and css data which MUST NOT come BEFORE the header function or you will get an error. you say it worked before BUT it will not have worked correctly as you are coding it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header function has to be sent before any html or css code. example below:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isLogged())
{
     header("location: mainarea.php");
     exit;  
}

function isLogged()
{return $_SESSION;}
?>

//css has to go below here

<html>
<head>
    //styles should go here
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a cookie-based session?  To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

Comment: yes, placing the session check before all, works... anyway it's really a mistery that without those css rule (but with the presence of some others) the script works... Adding this rule won't work anymre